# Case-insensitive regex that keeps capitalization after replacement?

Tags: python, regex

In Python, the following code lets me replace most sanely-written text case-consistently. It has bugs if, say, from_substring is "the" and my_string contains "theater," but this is just to illustrate what I want to do.

```
def cap_preserving_replace(my_string, from_substring, to_substring):
    temp = my_string.replace(from_substring.lower(), to_substring.lower())
    temp = temp.replace(from_substring.upper(), to_substring.upper())
    temp = temp.replace(from_substring.title(), to_substring.title())
    return temp
```

However, I also want (in much rarer cases) to be able to make the following sorts of conversions:

```
before -> afters
Before -> Afters
BEFORE -> AFTERS
BeFoRe -> AfTeRs
```

The general code I have is ugly. And while I probably just want to replace lower, upper and title cases, for which the code would be trivial, I am wondering if there is a good regex that can preserve capitalization schemes. The code below does so, converting `abc` to `def`.

```
import re

begin_string = 'abc'
end_string = 'def'

def case_keep_replace(my_string, begin_string = 'abc', end_string = 'def'):
    offsets = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(begin_string, my_string, re.IGNORECASE)]
    for x in offsets:
        temp_string = ''
        for y in range(0, len(begin_string)):
            if my_string[x+y].islower():
                temp_string += end_string[y]
            else:
                temp_string += end_string[y].upper()
        my_string = my_string[:x] + temp_string + my_string[x + len(temp_string):]
    return my_string

process_string = "All 8: abc, abC, aBc, aBC, Abc, AbC, ABc, ABC."

print("BEFORE:", process_string)
print("AFTERS: ", case_keep_replace(process_string))
```

Is there a suitable regex for case_keep_replace?

(Note: for `case_keep_replace`, the code should also check that from_substring and to_substring are the same length, but I wanted to focus the code chunk on the main question.)

Comment: Use a function as the replacement in `re.sub()`. It should look at the case pattern in the original string, and apply it to the replacement string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that you need to pass the `re.MatchData` object into the callback method, or a lambda, used as the second argument to `re.sub`.

However, your current code needs simplifying a bit, and here is how your code should look like:

```py
import re

def case_keep_replace(m, end_string):
    temp_string = ''
    for y in range(0, len(m.group())):
        if m.group()[y].islower():
            temp_string += end_string[y]
        else:
            temp_string += end_string[y].upper()
    return temp_string + end_string[y+1:]

# Now, testing
process_string = "All 8: abc, abC, aBc, aBC, Abc, AbC, ABc, ABC." # input string
begin_string = 'abc' # Actual pattern
end_string = 'def'   # Replacement string

print( process_string)
print( re.sub(begin_string, lambda m: case_keep_replace(m, end_string), process_string, flags=re.I) )
# => All 8: abc, abC, aBc, aBC, Abc, AbC, ABc, ABC.
#    All 8: def, deF, dEf, dEF, Def, DeF, DEf, DEF.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CriJ3v).

**Note**: I added `end_string[y+1:]` in th `return temp_string + end_string[y+1:]`, so as not to lose the rest of the `end_string` replacement, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Q7ljkf).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'd used functions before, but a bit simpler. So I'm disappointed I didn't sit back and make the full leap, and I very much appreciate you cleaning up my logic code.